# mat file upload StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HttpHandler -> Injector]

Tags: angular, http, angular-material, styles

Hi i working with Angular 9 and Angular Material... i want use the mat-file-upload, but when execute app this show the next error message: "StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HttpHandler -> Injector]"

[image: error]

I have really searched the internet quite a bit but I can't understand the problem ... I think it has to do with some injector or provider maybe, I miss that all the other components work fine.

TS Code

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatFileUploadModule } from 'mat-file-upload'  //this not work 
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button'; //this work!
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatFileUploadModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

HTML

```
<div class="common-container">
  <mat-file-upload></mat-file-upload>

  <button mat-button>Click me!</button> <!--works when not add mat-file-upload-->

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is hard to look at your code and find error. Can you use standard way from Angular?

1. create `material.module.ts` like this

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { 
  ...
} from '@angular/material';
import { MatFileUploadModule } from 'mat-file-upload';

@NgModule({
imports: [
  ...
  MatFileUploadModule
],
exports: [
  ...
  MatFileUploadModule
 ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

2. From your main module. Here I am using the `MatFileUploadModule` in `components.module.ts`, so I have to import `material.module.ts` to `components.module.ts`

   Note: I MUST import it to current module which is using your `material.module.ts`.

   I GUESS you do something wrong from this step.

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
...
import { MaterialModule } from '.../material.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...,
    MaterialModule
  ],
  exports: [
    ...
  ],
  entryComponents: [ 
    ...
  ]
})
export class ComponentsModule { }
```

This will solve your problem I think.